# Unity - Try to SignIn Player to GooglePlay with GooglePlay Services

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

im trying to sign the players into GooglePlay using the GooglePlay services. The app is already published.
When starting the game you should automatically sign in with GooglePlay but nothing happens.
This is the code Im using.
I would greatly apreciate if someone could help me on this topic.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;


public class GooglePlayServices : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    private void Initialize()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            .RequestServerAuthCode(false).
            Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        SignInUserWithPlayGames();
    }
    void SignInUserWithPlayGames()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(SignInInteractivity.CanPromptOnce, (success) =>
         {
             switch(success)
             {
                 case SignInStatus.Success:
                     Debug.Log("Signed in Player successfully");
                     break;
                 default:
                     Debug.Log("Login failed");
                     break;
             }
         });
    }

    public void SignInByHand()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(SignInInteractivity.CanPromptAlways, (success) =>
        {

        });
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SignOut();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Initialize()
{
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().RequestServerAuthCode(false).Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    SignInUserWithPlayGames();
}

void SignInUserWithPlayGames()
{
    if (!Social.localUser.authenticated)
    {
        Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => {
            if(success)
            {
                // signed in
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Try using Social instead of directly calling the Google Play Plugin. I only call the plugin directly if I need specific functionality that other Social platforms do not have.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Sadly it's still not working. GooglePlay don't even tries to connect the player. I guess the problem is somewhere else but in the code. Still GooglePlay already showed up when I just used the PlayPlatform.Instance.Authenticate() but than failed to connect.

Comment: I would try using logcat with Android Studio. The code above works for me. You need to be using the right SHA key. Make sure you are using the release and not debugging key. When using logcat, you can figure out exactly why it is failing. I assume it has to do with the setup outside of the c# code.